# Why choose Gaussian when calculating the volumes of high dimensional spheres?

Tags: geometry

When calculating the volumes of high dimensional spheres, it's difficult to do it in cartesian coordinates so we choose to integrate Gaussian in both cartesian and polar coordinates and solve the equation. But why do we choose Gaussian at the first place? Just because it's spherically symmetric?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a sphere involves the sum $x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots +x_n^2$.

Functions of several variables are easy to integrate when they are  products* of functions of one variable: $f_1(x_1)f_2(x_2)\cdots f_n(x_n)$.

The exponential function converts sums into products. And since we want the integral over $\mathbb R^n$ to be finite, the exponential should be decaying, i.e., $\exp(-(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots +x_n^2))$.

---

*Sums work well, too. But for $f(x_1^2+x_2^2+\dots+ x_n^2)$ to decompose in this way, $f$ would have to be linear. But then the integral over $\mathbb R^n$ is infinite.